# Magento 2 : Remove wishlist item event

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, wishlist

I just want to execute some code during remove wishlist item like m1 does with `controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove` event. I have checked with Magento 2 all events on https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/ URL. There is no event for remove wishlist item.

**Is there any way to perform this?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller_action_predispatch` event executed in every action of Magento and the event you are talking about is dynamic that's why you are not able to find in the link which you have provided and in core Magento.

Not let's check your event `controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove` in this event `controller_action_predispatch` is static event name and `wishlist_index_remove` is your action (I mean to remove item from the wishlist). Magento create this dynamic event on every action.

Just look in this [line](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php#L98) of `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`  class

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'controller_action_predispatch_' . $request->getFullActionName(),
            $eventParameters
        );
```

You can see `controller_action_predispatch_` is statically written and  `$request->getFullActionName()` is dynamic. So in your case you are performing removing Item from wishlist so your full action name `wishlist_index_remove` that's why your event name replace by `controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove`